# Migrate war from OAS10g to weblogic server 12c

Tags: weblogic, war, weblogic12c, migrate

I have a war application running on OAS 10G, and connected to oracle database 12.1.0, and I need to move it to a weblogic server 12c.

I have deployed the war on weblogic server after creating a datasource to the same database server for OAS Application, the new app is running but when I try to connect to my app it doesn't work, tnsping and telnet work fine between servers, also data source test.

is there others thing to do except copy the war from OAS to Weblogic, create datasource and deploy the app, Can you please help on that.

Comment: Did you check weblogic log files ? Are you sure your application is started and not only installed in Weblogic ?

Comment: I didn't find anything in log files, what do you mean by started not installed ? the app is deployed and the datasource test is success.

Comment: In the admin console check the status of your application : it would be "Active"

Comment: the status is active